# SQL Query output cannot be exported to a CSV file

Tags: export, datagrip

Hello I currently working with a SQL dump in Datagrip. I just wrote a SQL Query which I want to export to a CSV file unfortunately I get a error message if I try to export it the export error message as follows says:
Cannot write file: /home/*NAME*.csv

An hour before I successfully exported a Query with no Problems. I didn't changed a thing in the Database except for adding another table. The Table was created as a help table to write an SQL Query on the former Query

Maybe someone encountered the Problem before and there is a easy way to solve. If additional Information is needed please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: It could be a permissions problem, or not enough disk space.

Comment: Try to choose another directory for export

Comment: Hey thanks for the fast response. I dont know exactly how but after a few more tries I was able to save to my project folder. I dont know what produced the error there. But thanks.